# Scala compiler error - sha256 not a member of DigestUtils - why does 1.6 work, but 1.9-SNAPSHOT does not?

Tags: scala, apache-commons-codec

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.9-SNAPSHOT"
val bytes = DigestUtils.sha256(message)
```

Throws compiler error:

```
value sha256 is not a member of object 
org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
```

But when I go to look at the docs, it's clearly a static method returning a byte array.

When I use:

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6"
```

The same code works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct artifact coordinates? There's no 1.9-SNAPSHOT listed [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1511838660), nor [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec)

Comment: [Looks like](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/codec/trunk/pom.xml?revision=1539776&view=markup) the coordinates are correct. Just for fun, have you verified the repo you're fetching the snapshot from is correct and that the jar looks as it should? I've found weird things happen with snapshot versions. Maybe you should download the source, build yourself, and install in your local `m2` just to see what happens.

Comment: I'm using the Sonatype public repository [here](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~commons-codec~commons-codec~~~~kw,versionexpand)

Comment: And rolling back to 1.8 fixed it for me.